# Android libaums: device.init() eject the device

Tags: java, android

My goal is to read the content of a USB key on an android tablet.
I am currently using a small project before integrating this feature to my initial app.
I am using the libaums library as follow:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbDevice;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbManager;

import me.jahnen.libaums.core.UsbMassStorageDevice;
import me.jahnen.libaums.core.fs.*;
import me.jahnen.libaums.*;
import me.jahnen.*;
import me.jahnen.libaums.core.fs.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "com.emteria.usbpermissions.USB_PERMISSION";

    Button btnLoad;
    TextView tvLoad;
    TextView tvUsb;
    String fileName, filePath, fileContent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnLoad = findViewById(R.id.btnLoad);
        tvLoad = findViewById(R.id.tvLoad);
        tvUsb = findViewById(R.id.tvUsb);
        fileName = "myFile.txt";
        filePath = "myFileDir";

        //btnLoad.setEnabled(isExternalStorageAvailableForRW());
        tvUsb.setText("tv usb");
        btnLoad.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });

        UsbMassStorageDevice[] devices = UsbMassStorageDevice.getMassStorageDevices(this /* Context or Activity */);
        int deviceNumber = devices.length;
        tvLoad.setText(String.valueOf(deviceNumber));
        UsbManager usbManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);

        for(UsbMassStorageDevice device: devices) {
            BroadcastReceiver usbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    synchronized (this) {
                        if (intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false)) {
                            // La permission a été accordée, exécutez votre code ici
                            tvUsb.setText("Permission granted");
//                            FileSystem currentFs = device.getPartitions().get(0).getFileSystem();

                            try {
                                device.init();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                Log.e("USB", e.getMessage());
                                tvUsb.setText(e.getMessage());
                            }
                        } else {
                            tvUsb.setText("Permission denied");
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
            registerReceiver(usbReceiver, filter);

            PendingIntent permissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                    this, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
            usbManager.requestPermission(device.getUsbDevice(), permissionIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is when I am calling device.init(), the USB key is ejected from the tablet without throwing any error.
After that, an error is thrown explaining that there is no more USB device and the maximum try number has been reached.

Has somebody an idea to solve the problem ?

Here is the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.emteria.usbpermissions.USB_PERMISSION" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USB_PERMISSION" />


</manifest>
```

I am running the app on Android 8.
Thanks for help !